# Implementation of wait_for within the iteration

Tags: timeout, iteration, ansible, ansible-2.x

How do we extend the scope of the wait_items to span multiple task items with a wait_for (sleep) in between.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Debug1
    debug: msg="Debug1 -  {{item}} " <-- Errors out here

  - name: Wait Buffer
    wait_for: timeout=10

    with_items: ["dir1","dir2"]
```

The idea has to perform a task sequentially from the list and wait couple of seconds and then move the next item

Answer (score 0):

> How do we extend the scope of the wait_items to span multiple task items with a wait_for (sleep) in between.

You should use shell module with 'with_items' and add there sleep or wait until file will exit.

PS:

Fixed version:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Debug1
    debug: msg="Debug1 -  {{item}} "
    with_items: ["dir1","dir2"]

  - name: Wait Buffer
    wait_for: timeout=10
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it still produces the results of dir1, dir2, then wait. I am looking for something with dir1, wait and then dir2.